# siunitx not making numbers bold

Tags: siunitx, bold

So I'm trying to make the number resulting from the expression in `\num` command bold:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\begin{document}    
    \textbf{\$36,717}  $-$ \textbf{\$25,640} = \$$\mathbf{\num[bracket-negative-numbers]{\fpeval{36717 - 25640}}}$
    
    \textbf{\$36,717}  $-$ \textbf{\$25,640} = \$$\mathbf{\num[bracket-negative-numbers, evaluate-expression]{36717 - 25640}}$
    
    \textbf{\$36,717}  $-$ \textbf{\$25,640} = \$$\boldmath{\num[bracket-negative-numbers]{\fpeval{36717 - 25640}}}$
    
    \textbf{\$36,717}  $-$ \textbf{\$25,640} = \$$\boldmath{\num[bracket-negative-numbers, evaluate-expression]{36717 - 25640}}$
    
    Desired: \textbf{\$11,077}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Current output]

As shown, neither `\mathbf` nor `\boldmath` do anything. On the other hand, if I put either of the two in the input portion (that is, the braces portion) of the `\num` command, then I get an error. How to make the answer from the expression bold?

Also, can someone explain the difference between `\num[evaluate-expression]{...}` and `\fpeval{...}`, if there are any?

Comment: There is no difference according to the manual. “By enabling the evaluate-expression option, the input can be processed by the standard LATEX3 fpu (see package xfp for more).”

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel got it, thank you!

Comment: As per manual `\sisetup{propagate-math-font = true, reset-math-version = false}` makes it pick up the `\mathbf`. Or dou you want `\num` do just typeset all numbers in bold?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel just want to make the numbers bold when I want to. I just tried, and it worked for `\mathbf` but not for `\boldmath`. I wonder why.

Comment: your switches between text mode and math mode looks rather curious. Why do you type the minus as math but the equal sign not? \boldmath should not be used inside math, you get a warning in the log `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \boldmath invalid in math mode`, and if you want siunitx to follow the mathversion, use `reset-math-version=false`. See section 4.2. in the documentation.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer says, you should first decide if you want to print these numbers in text or math mode. I suspect text mode ...

Comment: Ulrike and Joseph, I initially switch between text and math mode because the minus sign in text would look different from that in math mode. I put the numbers in text mode because I originally did not know of the ability to do the same thing in math mode with the separator with `siunitx`.

Comment: On the `evaluate-expression` 'bonus question': in v2 of `siunitx`, there was no built-in expression evaluation as it predated the code behind `\fpeval`. So to evaluate something you needed `\num{\fpeval{...}}`. For v3, I have included the ability to work out expressions directly, but you need to activate it as it's otherwise possible to confuse the nature of the input.

Answer (score 2):

For text mode printing, you want to set `reset-text-series = false`. Setting printing in text and making a couple of custom commands to have a more structured input, you might go with

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    % Unrelated to the bold issue,
    % but to get the desired output format
    group-separator = {,},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    bracket-negative-numbers,
    % Automatically 'do maths'
    evaluate-expression ,
    % Use text mode for printing numbers,
    % and allow them to be bold
    mode = text ,
    reset-text-series = false
  }
% Make a couple of custom commands for the document
\NewDocumentCommand\dollarvalue{m}{\text{\$}\num{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\boldvalue{m}{\text{\textbf{\dollarvalue{#1}}}}
\begin{document}    
  $\boldvalue{36717} - \boldvalue{25640} = \boldvalue{36717 - 25640}$
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you want to print in math mode but have `\boldmath` apply to values printed by `siunitx`, then you want `reset-math-version = false`. Again making things a bit more organised, this time not using a separate command for bold values:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    % Unrelated to the bold issue,
    % but to get the desired output format
    group-separator = {,},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    bracket-negative-numbers,
    % Automatically 'do maths'
    evaluate-expression ,
    % Allow math values to be bold
    reset-math-version = false
  }
% Make a ccustom command for the document
\NewDocumentCommand\dollarvalue{m}{\$\num{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \boldmath
  $\dollarvalue{36717} - \dollarvalue{25640} = \dollarvalue{36717 - 25640}$
\end{document}
```